# Socket message sending crash

Tags: python, sockets, networking, send, packets

I have a series of messages being sent through a socket running in a separate thread. A short time after sending a message, the cpu usage from the process drops to almost nothing, my main thread stops running, and its memory allocation skyrockets almost crashing my computer.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? How have you fixed it?

Comment: Could you provide some code which reproduces the problem as part of your question? At the moment, it's hard to answer the question as there aren't enough details.

Comment: @matthewatabet If it's code related I don't want anyone to have to look through all of it. I just simply want to know if anyone has experienced a similar problem trying to send simple messages and if so how they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before but only for large messages.
Basically messages over socket have a limitation of about 65,000 bytes (2^16)

So, there's this limitation in core linux OS which doesn't allow the socket PIPE to communicate more than this at a time. If it does send more data that the limit, the socket meta information is overwritten and the parent thread "loses" the child thread - And it doesnt know that its lost the child thread ! So, it keeps waiting for the child thread to send it some sort of information.

This makes the parent thread hang and your child thread keeps sending information - which eats up your memory.

The way to avoid this is to use a tempfile to send information from one side to the other.

#### About the earlier mentioned tempfile method:

I'm not very sure how your code is, so I am explaining how I used tempfiles in my usecase.

So, as socket pipes have a limitation, the obvious choice is to use some other method to transfer messages from one process to another. When I came across this, I was trying to communicate between a child and a parent process.

The way I was doing it was:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["some_command"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print(process.stdout.readlines())
```

Now, when I got the error, I used a temporary file using the `tempfile` module in python, like so:

```
import subprocess
stdout_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
process = subprocess.Popen(["some_command"], stdout=stdout_file)
process.wait()
stdout_file.seek(0)
print(stdout_file.read().decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

Comment: Just the kind of response I was looking for! it would make a lot of sense if this was the behavior that is occurring. Can you elaborate a little more on the tempfile method? I'm pretty new to using sockets.

Comment: It seems the largest message I am sending is 448 bytes.

Comment: Ah - then it's not the same problem. Can't say more unless I see your code

Comment: @AFK Ah, I see your edit. I'm communicating between a client and server so I'm unable to use a tempfile in this way. Unfortunately I cannot post the code in a public space